# How to have a field displayed depending on user's role in Views?

Tags: views, 8

I use Views module to display the content of a custom entity with Page view (not Block view).
I'd like to have one field displayed only if the user has a certain role.
What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Page view or Block view?

Comment: Page view (updated my question...).

Comment: Does it make a difference?

Comment: for the solution I had in mind, yes, as it only works for blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a custom entity you may consider overriding the checkFieldAccess method of Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityAccessControlHandler.

Then assign your own handler as handlers/access in @ContentEntityType.

But it's only me who prefers being in coding hell instead of configuration hell :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a custom Entity maybe this module will works for you

https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

Thanks!.